# How do I determine the end point of a UITextVIew?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

How do I determine the end point of a UIVIew? I know you can do `self.descriptionTextView.bounds.origin.y` but that doesn't take into account the size of the view.

Can I do something like: `self.descriptionTextView.bounds.origin.y+(unsigned long)listingShortDescription.length+10`

thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by "end point"? The coordinate of the bottom edge of the text view?

Comment: bounds.origin.y will always be zero.

Comment: @Schoob Not in a UITextView (which is a UIScrollView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.descriptionTextView.bounds.origin.y will give you 0
as bounds have an origin of CGPointZero.
Use frame instead.
self.descriptionTextView.frame.origin.y + self.descriptionTextView.frame.size.height

Better yet:

```
CGRectGetMaxY(self.descriptionTextView.frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRectMaxYEdge(self.descriptionTextView.frame);
```

This will give you the coordinate if the bottom edge of the text view in the coordinate space of its parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function CGRectGetMaxY()

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html